# Find $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(2014!)!(k!)!}{((2014+k)!)!}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, factorial

> Find $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^\infty\dfrac{1}{\left(\binom{2014+k}{2014}\right)}$, where $\left(\binom{a}{b}\right)=\dfrac{(a!)!}{(b!)!\left((a-b)!\right)!}$

I tried using an easy method that worked for $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^\infty\dfrac{1}{\binom{2014+k}{2014}}$, but it didn't work due to the nested gamma functions that appeared.

Comment: This looks like a contest problem. Is it?

Comment: @DanielR Oh no no it isn't at all :) I just love $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^\infty\dfrac{1}{\binom{2014+k}{2014}}$, and yesterday someone showed me another sum with double factorials, so I thought of that new version (unless I've created by chance a problem that has been asked in a contest in the past :D )

Comment: Maple produces $0.02895264763$. If you need more digits, please, let me know.

Comment: @user64494 Look at my edit. Could you please find the new correct value ?

Comment: The notation for double factorial is $n!!$ not $(n!)!,$ if that's what you mean in your comment.

Comment: And the meaning (not only notation) of the "[double factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial)" is different.